# 10,000 HTTP requests per minute performance

Tags: sql-server, azure, web-scraping, web-crawler, httpwebrequest

I'm fairly experienced with web crawlers, however, this question is in regards to performance and scale. I'm needing to request and crawl 150,000 urls over an interval(most urls are every 15 minutes which makes it about 10,000 requests per minute). These pages have a decent amount of data(around 200kb per page). Each of the 150,000 urls exist in our database(MSSQL) with a timestamp of the last crawl date, and an interval for so we know when to crawl again.

This is where we get an extra layer of complexity. They do have an API which allows for up to 10 items per call. The information we need exists partially only in the API, and partially only on the web page. The owner is allowing us to make web calls and their servers can handle it, however, they can not update their API or provide direct data access.

So the flow should be something like: Get 10 records from the database that intervals have passed and need to be crawled, then hit the API. Then each item in the batch of 10 needs their own separate web-requests. Once the request returns the HTML we parse it and update records in our database.

I am interested in getting some advice on the correct way to handle the infrastructure. Assuming a multi-server environment some business requirements:

- Once a URL record is ready to be crawled, we want to ensure it is only grabbed and ran by a single server. If two servers check it out simultaneously and run, it can corrupt our data.
- The workload can vary, currently, it is 150,000 url records, but that can go much lower or much higher. While I don't expect more than a 10% change per day, having some sort of auto-scale would be nice.
- After each request returns the HTML we need to parse it and update records in our database with the individual data pieces. Some host providers allow free incoming data but charge for outgoing. So ideally the code base that requests the webpage and then parses the data also has direct SQL access. (As opposed to a micro-service approach)

Something like a multi-server blocking collection(Azure queue?), autoscaling VMs that poll the queue, single database host server which is also queried by MVC app that displays data to users. 
Any advice or critique is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider using Azure Functions (Capacity Plan)? Recent improvements in the platform enables scaling out instances to cope with increasing load much faster, the same applies to scale back in to save money. Moreover, manageability is easier compared to VMs (e.g. hardened images, patching, etc.). Event Hub could be a possible trigger, it supports high throughput and provides replay capabilities. Also, can you provide more details on the SQL Server tier (e.g. partitioning, indexes, multiple servers, mod hashing, etc.), since it will likely become a bottleneck first :P

Comment: Also, try to avoid Azure Storage Queues when scalability is at stake, because they represent a single partition (limited 2000 TPS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Messaging**

I echo Evandro's comment and would explore Service Bus Message Queues of Event Hubs for loading a queue to be processed by your compute nodes.   Message Queues support record locking which based on your write up might be attractive.

**Compute Options**

I also agree that Azure Functions would provide a good platform for scaling your compute/processing operations (calling the API & scraping HTML).  In addition Azure Functions can be triggered by Message Queues, Event Hubs OR Event Grid.  [Note: Event Grid allows you to connect various Azure services (pub/sub) with durable messaging.  So it might play a helpful middle-man role in your scenario.]

Another option for compute could be Azure Container Instances (ACI) as you could spin up containers on demand to process your records.  This does not have the same auto-scaling capability that Functions does though and also does not support the direct binding operations.

**Data Processing Concern (Ingress/Egress)**

Indeed Azure does not charge for data ingress but any data leaving Azure will have an egress charge after the initial 5 GB each month. [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/]

You should be able to have the Azure Functions handle calling the API, scraping the HTML and writing to the database.  You might have to break those up into separated Functions but you can chain Functions together easily either directly or with LogicApps.